# Definition of $ \arcsin $

Tags: calculus, functions

The definition I knew for the inverse of the sin, is the following:

for $ x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] $ we have:

$ \sin x=y $ $ \iff $ $ x=\arcsin y+2\pi k $.

But recently I've seen that we could also define

$ \sin x=y $ $\iff $ $ x=\pi-\arcsin y+2\pi k $.

How's this two definitions correlate? when do you we choose the first one and when do we chose the other? why does it lead to the same result ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to real-valued functions, $\arcsin$ is the inverse of the function $\left.\sin\right\rvert_{\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]}:\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]\to[-1,1]$, i.e. the section of $\sin$ with domain $[-1,1]$ and range in $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$.

As for solving $\sin y=x$ in $y$ for some $x\in[-1,1]$, we have $$\sin y=x\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\Bbb Z,(y=2k\pi+\arcsin x\lor y=(2k+1)\pi-\arcsin x)$$

which essentially covers the fact that for all $x\in[-1,1]$ there are two real numbers $\alpha\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $\sin \alpha=x$.

For instance, if you want the ones in $[0,2\pi)$, you'll have to consider $\arcsin x$ and $\pi-\arcsin x$ if $x\ge0$, or $2\pi+\arcsin x$ and $\pi-\arcsin x$ if $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$$
$${}{}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1523035)

Comment: @tortue: I think it does, that's all one needs to know in order to clarify the OP's doubt.